# Does dapper.contrib support primary key in varchar type?

Tags: dapper

I am new to Dapper, trying to write some code to test Dapper.Contrib.

```
[Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.Table("Cat")]
public class Cat
{
    [Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.Key]
    public string catid {get;set;}
    public string catName {get;set;}
}
...
Cat cat = new Cat(){catid="somecharmaybe", catName="testcat"}
conn.Insert(cat);
```

When I run the application, following exception is thrown

> can not insert null value to primary key catid

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this extension: https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can not insert null value to primary key catid

The error says you cant insert null value on catid because dapper understand that this is identity key which is generated by the database to solve this use DapperExtension

```
public class Cat
{
    public string catid {get;set;}
    public string catName {get;set;}
}

public class CatMap : ClassMapper<Cat>
{
   public CatMap()
   {
       Table("Cat")
       Map(s=>s.CatId).Key(KeyType.Assigned);
       AutoMap();
   } 
}
```

i hope it help, if anyone has better solution kindly post it here thank you.